# Python3 selenoid can't ignore SSL certificate verification

Tags: python, selenium, ssl, ngrok, selenoid

I'm trying to control selenoid from another network computer.

Make drivers with this

```
self.drivers.append(webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='http://e2f5a65c53.ngrok.io/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=capabilities))
```

when I run this code getting this error

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 464, in connect
    _match_hostname(cert, self.assert_hostname or server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 512, in _match_hostname
    match_hostname(cert, asserted_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 416, in match_hostname
    raise CertificateError("hostname %r "
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: ("hostname '3.22.30.40' doesn't match either of '*.ngrok.io', 'ngrok.io'",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ryo/Dropbox/Mac/Desktop/selenium_for_beWinning/autoTradeGUI.py", line 4, in <module>
    trading = Trading()
  File "/Users/ryo/Dropbox/Mac/Desktop/selenium_for_beWinning/main.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.driver.append(webdriver.Remote(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 374, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 402, in _request
    resp = http.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 78, in request
    return self.request_encode_body(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 170, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 417, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(method, redirect_location, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 375, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 783, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 783, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='3.22.30.40', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError("hostname '3.22.30.40' doesn't match either of '*.ngrok.io', 'ngrok.io'")))
```

Then I tried to ignore SSL certificate verification.

```
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

by this line of code

but still getting the same error

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `acceptInsecureCerts = true` capability. This will not work when your web site has strict transport security (HSTS) enabled.

Comment: Thanks, sir!  It worked. but ngrok has a connections limit.  Is there any other way to connect selenoid from another network?